# Images Resize bin/magento catalog:images:resize too slow

Tags: magento2, php, image-resize

Magento 2.4.5  on 4GB RAM 2 CORE CLOUD SERVER

Hi

When running this command bin/magento catalog:images:resize

it has taken 2 days which is 48 hours to complete 50% so another 2 days are needed to complete the task. 4 days !  it is showing 56826 images

is this correct behaviour?
Is there any way to make this process faster?
there is 4GB on server and we have dedicated all of it Magento - disabled elasticsearch and crons. but it doesnt make any difference - the command is not using up max available RAM

Comment: It depends how many product you have, if it is in billions it will take long time.
Another way is you can use reindex command.

Comment: there are  35000 products - please explain more about the reindex command how does this help and how can it be used for this task

Comment: Just you need to run php bin/magento index:reindex command and check.
Let me know is it helpful.

Comment: how does running that help with image resize? not making sense 2 commands do different things

Comment: images resize is one aspect of storage requirements.  reindex assists in making queries complete in less time (and helps reduce resource requirements).  With a 4G and 2 Core server, performance may be disappointing, depending on results of @@max_used_connections; - which is max used concurrent connections since instance was started.  If this is more than 20, consider a system with more RAM and Cores.